# What am I doing wrong in my basic bubble sort?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, bubble-sort

I am trying to make a basic bubble sort and count the number of passes and swaps it takes to complete.

So for the example input:

`23` - This is just the amount of numbers below.. Don't ask why I can't just use the len()

`20 18 8 11 17 12 13 21 10 14 9 5 19 6 16 7 2 15 1 3 22 4 23`

```
def bubbleSort(amount, numbers):
    sorted = False
    swapCount, passCount = 0,0

    while not sorted:
        sorted = True
        for i in range(amount-1):
            if numbers[i] > numbers[i+1]:
                sorted = False
                swapCount += 1
                numbers[i], numbers[i+1] = numbers[i+1], numbers[i]
        passCount += 1
    print(numbers)
    print('%s %s') % (passCount, swapCount)

bubbleSort(input(),raw_input().split())
```

Naturally, the expected output would be:

19 passes, 151 swaps, and the list in correct order least to greatest.
However, I keep ending up with 19 passes and 109 swaps and my order looking like this:

`['1', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '2', '20', '21', '22', '23', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']`

Can anyone steer me in the right direction as to how I can sort things properly and `2` isn't considered greater than `10`?

Comment: Please don't tag your question as 'solved'. The system does that for you when you accept an answer.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes My bad, I forgot to remove that. My question was solved within a minute or two so I edited in the (Solved) tag to save people a wasted click into my question. (You mark a correct answer until 10 minutes have passed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `raw_input().split()` is a list of strings, not integers. Your algorithm is correct -- you're sorting the strings in alphabetical order.

A quick fix is to use e.g.

```
bubbleSort(input(), [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()])
```